# Why Google pubsub java8 client is receiving duplicate messages even after acknowledgement?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

We are using google-cloud-pubsub (0.24.0-beta) pull client for reading messages from subscriber and seeing high rate of duplicates in that. Google documentation says that little duplication is expected but in our case, we are seeing 80% of messages are getting duplicated even after acknowledgement.

The most weird part is, even if we acknowledge the message immediately in receiver using consumer.ack(), duplicates are still occurring. 
Does anybody know how to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A large number of message duplicates could be the result of [flow control settings](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/latest/apidocs/com/google/cloud/pubsub/v1/Subscriber.Builder.html#setFlowControlSettings(com.google.api.gax.batching.FlowControlSettings)) being set too high or too low. If your flow control settings are too high, where you are allowing too many messages to be outstanding to your client at the same time, then it is possible that the acks are being set too late. If this is the cause, you would probably see the CPU of your machine at or near 100%. In this case, try setting the max number of outstanding messages or bytes to a lower number.

It could also be the case that the flow control settings are set too low. Some messages get buffered in the client before they are delivered to your MessageReceiver, particularly if you are flow controlled. In this case, messages may spend too much time buffered in the client before they are delivered. There is an issue with messages in this state that is being fixed in [an outstanding PR](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/pull/2478). In this scenario, you could either increase your max outstanding bytes or messages (up to whatever your subscriber can actually handle) or you can try to [setAckExpirationPadding](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/latest/apidocs/com/google/cloud/pubsub/v1/Subscriber.Builder.html#setAckExpirationPadding(org.threeten.bp.Duration)) to a larger value than the default 500ms.

It is also worth checking your publisher to see if it is unexpectedly publishing messages multiple times. If that is the case, you may see the contents of your messages being the same, but they aren't duplicate messages being generated by Google Cloud Pub/Sub itself.

**Edited to mention bug that was in the client library:**

If you were using a version of google-cloud-pubsub between v0.22.0 and v0.29.0, you might have been running into an issue where a change in the underlying mechanism for getting messages could [result in excessive duplicates](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/2465). The issue has since been fixed.

Comment: In my use case, publisher publish approx 50k messages in a minute and then on subscriber side, following are my config:
1. FlowControlSetting MaxOutstandingElementCount is set equivalent to ExecutorThreadCount . Say 20.
2. MaxAckExtensionPeriod is set to 1 hour.
With this too, i can see duplicates.

I first tried with higher value of FlowControlSetting (than ExecutorThreadCount) but that too didn't work and hence, i thought to set them equivalent. We even tried Sync pull but that is also resulting in same problem.

Comment: If it is happening even if you are using the synchronous pull API, that makes me think it is likely that you have duplicates in your publishing. Are your publishes failing at all and being retried? Also, what is the ack deadline set to on your subscription?

Comment: Thanks for replying Kamal. 

To avoid publishing duplicate, I always first check from stackdriver monitoring dashboard that i have no messages in it when i start publishing and then i ensure that messages published are unique. Hence i am sure that publishing part isn't sending duplicates. 

Yes, my messages are coming down to zero, if my subscriber isn't doing any processing and just acknowledging it immediately. 

Ack deadline is set to 600s.

Comment: I tried again with Synchronous Pull API and observed that it is duplicating in case it has possibility to take time longer than ackDeadline. Since I had setMaxMessages:100 and each message was taking 10s so it was going beyong ackDeadline (600s) when received messages were greater than 60 approx. And when i changed message processing time to 5s, duplicates were not visible. This means that Pull synchronous API is working fine but I can still see issue with Pull Async API (which is our preferred choice). Can we do something to fix same in Pull Async API?